# Command to set the window width

Tags: macvim, textwidth

Using MacVim, I can manually drag the edge of the window (watching the numbers in the title bar) to whatever width I want.

Is there a command that will just immediately set it to a desired width?  I tried `:set winminwidth=100` and `:set winwidth=100`, but they had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

To change the width of the gVim window to 100 I would do:

```
:set columns=100
```

More information with `:h 'columns'`

Remark: According to @romainl it also works also on some terminal for vim.

To change the width of the current split to 100 I would do:

```
:vertical resize 100
```

More information with: `:h :vertical-resize`

Comment: Note, using `:set columns=` will only work in a gui version of vim.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, nope, it also works in some terminals.

Comment: okay, than clarification: `it does not necessarily work in terminal vim`

Comment: OP is asking about the GUI version anyway.

Comment: I know, but that doesn't mean other readers that stumble upon this will know. So I think this should be clarified

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat different answer, but I use this to change **both my window-size and font-size** at the same time -- remapping `FontSizeMinuts` and `FontSizePlus` to <kbd>F9</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd> respectively. This lives in my `.gvimrc`:

This is my default font, whose size `14` appears at the end of the string. This should work with any font whose size appears at the end.

```
set guifont=Tlwg\ Mono\ Bold\ 14
```

These functions will automatically increment or decrement my fontsize.

```
"================Adaptively resizing font=================

if has("unix")
    function! FontSizePlus ()
      let l:gf_size_whole = matchstr(&guifont, '\( \)\@<=\d\+$')
      let l:gf_size_whole = l:gf_size_whole + 2
      let l:new_font_size = ' '.l:gf_size_whole
      let &guifont = substitute(&guifont, ' \d\+$', l:new_font_size, '')
    endfunction

    function! FontSizeMinus ()
      let l:gf_size_whole = matchstr(&guifont, '\( \)\@<=\d\+$')
      let l:gf_size_whole = l:gf_size_whole - 2
      let l:new_font_size = ' '.l:gf_size_whole
      let &guifont = substitute(&guifont, ' \d\+$', l:new_font_size, '')
    endfunction
else
    function! FontSizePlus ()
      let l:gf_size_whole = matchstr(&guifont, '\(:h\)\@<=\d\+$')
      let l:gf_size_whole = l:gf_size_whole + 1
      let l:new_font_size = ':h'.l:gf_size_whole
      let &guifont = substitute(&guifont, ':h\d\+$', l:new_font_size, '')
    endfunction

    function! FontSizeMinus ()
      let l:gf_size_whole = matchstr(&guifont, '\(:h\)\@<=\d\+$')
      let l:gf_size_whole = l:gf_size_whole - 1
      let l:new_font_size = ':h'.l:gf_size_whole
      let &guifont = substitute(&guifont, ':h\d\+$', l:new_font_size, '')
    endfunction
endif
```

Then, this part binds these functions to <kbd>F9</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd>.

```
if has("gui_running")
    nmap <F9> :call FontSizeMinus()<CR>
    nmap <F10> :call FontSizePlus()<CR>
endif
```

Comment: Reading the code I have the impression that it only change the font size and not the number of columns. The size of the window is only affected because of the font size change. Do I have the correct understanding?

Comment: That is correct! It doesn't change the number of columns -- the window size is modified by changing the size of the font.

Comment: Prefer `:nnoremap` unless you need recursive mappings.